# Is there any differences in concept of "Najes" between Shia & Sunni

Tags: najis

There is some differences between Ahkam احکام of shia and sunni.

Is there something Najes نجس in sunni which is clean in shia or ViseVersa?

Comment: There are differences between sunni jurusprudence schools already.

Comment: [I tried to translate this](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa23766), but it was long and I got tired :/

Comment: @polfosol Merci